# Rails 3 & Devise : Notificatios related to sign up confirmation not working

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, notifications

I'm using devise for my Rails 3.2.9 application. The notifications related to confirmation (as below in devise.en.yml file , under en, devise, confirmations) do not appear after sign up. After sign up the user is redirected to sign in page without any notification but the email is sent. Once the user clicks on confirmation link in email he's redirected to the welcome page of the application, again without any notification on signing in or signing up successfully

**devise.en.yml:**

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:#THESE ARE NOT WORKING
      confirmed: "Your account was successfully confirmed. You are now signed in."
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions about how to confirm your account in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive an email with instructions about how to confirm your account in a few minutes."
    failure:#WORKS
      already_authenticated: "You are already signed in."
      inactive: "Your account was not activated yet."
      invalid: "Invalid email or password."
      invalid_token: "Invalid authentication token."
      locked: "Your account is locked."
      not_found_in_database: "Invalid email or password."
      timeout: "Your session expired, please sign in again to continue."
      unauthenticated: "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
      unconfirmed: "You have to confirm your account before continuing."
    mailer:
      confirmation_instructions:
        subject: "Confirmation instructions"
      reset_password_instructions:
        subject: "Reset password instructions"
      unlock_instructions:
        subject: "Unlock Instructions"
     #some code..
```

**EDIT:**

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      confirmed: "Your account was successfully confirmed. You are now signed in."
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions about how to confirm your account in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive an email with instructions about how to confirm your account in a few minutes."
    failure:
      already_authenticated: "You are already signed in."
      inactive: "Your account was not activated yet."
      invalid: "Invalid email or password."
      invalid_token: "Invalid authentication token."
    -----------#SOME CODE---------------
    user_registrations:
      user:
        destroyed: "Bye! Your account was successfully cancelled. We hope to see you again soon."
        signed_up: "Welcome! You have signed up successfully."
        signed_up_but_inactive: "You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is not yet activated."
        signed_up_but_locked: "You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is locked."
        signed_up_but_unconfirmed: "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please open the link to activate your account."
        update_needs_confirmation: "You updated your account successfully, but we need to verify your new email address. Please check your email and click on the confirm link to finalize confirming your new email address."
        updated: "You updated your account successfully."
     -----------#SOME CODE---------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following lines in your application.html.erb:

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

Comment: I'm using another layout file in app/views/layouts called layout.html.erb and i'm using the same in all my controllers. I have the following code in layout.html.erb and application.html.erb
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :section, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => "flash" %>
  <% end %>

Comment: i am not sure, but try :class => "#{name}"

Comment: My question is why is it not working only for confirmation notifications? it works for others!

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem @akshatha ? I added :confirmable to an existing user model, and notifications don't work, but only for :confirmanble

Comment: Hi GregoireC, Its working for me now.. But I dont exactly remember what did the trick..I went thru my svn revisions and what I saw was I have added the two lines to application.html.erb as suggested by sunny1304 and as I had created new registration controller extending devise's I changed the devise.en.yml yo use that hierarchy.. I'll show it in my EDIT